# Why duplicate_or_move_bug_status can only be RESOLVED or VERIFIED?

Tags: bugzilla

Could someone please explain to me why in Bugzilla (I'm using 4.4.1) **duplicate_or_move_bug_status** can only be **RESOLVED** or **VERIFIED**?

My rather newbe intuition tells me that it should follow the status of the bug it duplicates especially if that other bug is not resolved nor verified.

Answer (score 0):

Check in **Administration->Bug Status workflow**.This defines what status our bugs may move from current status. You can edit this if you are a administrator.